# How to put a lock and transaction on table using spring 4 or above using jdbcTemplate and annotations like @Transactional?

Tags: spring, transactions, jdbctemplate, spring-java-config

I am trying to put lock on table while writing on table and if something happened in between then roll-back .

Trying to convert below code

```
lock table test_g1 read;
lock table test_g write;

-- BEGIN;
START TRANSACTION;

insert into test_g1 values(143);
insert into test_g values(145);
select * from test_g1;
select * from test_g;
Rollback;

select * from test_g;
unlock tables;
```

How to convert above code into @Transactional spring jdbcTemplate code?

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor={DataAccessException.class})
     public void Test(){
        jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into test1 (id, nam) values (4, 'A')");
        throw new DataAccessException("error") {
         };
     }
```

Here i am trying to throw error, so insert statement should rollback but it's not happening .

Thanks

**EDIT-1**
I am attaching the code , what exactly i am doing

In JdbcDaoImpl.java , i mentioned my problem as a comment above Test() .

**App.java**

```
package com.cgiri.javabrains.Spring4;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public class App 
{


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        App2 app2 = ctx.getBean("app2",App2.class);
     app2.call();  
    }
}
```

**App2.java**

```
package com.cgiri.javabrains.Spring4;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
@Component
public class App2 {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx = null;

    JdbcDaoImpl jdbcDaoImpl ;

    public void call(  )
    {
        jdbcDaoImpl =  ctx.getBean("jdbcDaoImpl",JdbcDaoImpl.class);

        System.out.println(jdbcDaoImpl.getCount());
        try{
            jdbcDaoImpl.Test();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        System.out.println(jdbcDaoImpl.getCount());


    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        this.ctx = context;

    }
}
```

**JdbcDaoImpl.java**

```
package com.cgiri.javabrains.Spring4;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;



@Component
@Transactional
public class JdbcDaoImpl {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test1";
        // jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class);
    }

    public void crateTable() {
        String sql = "create table if not exists test1 (id integer, nam char(50))";
        jdbcTemplate.execute(sql);
        jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into test1 (id, nam) values (1, 'A')");
        int count = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from test1",Integer.class);    

        System.out.println(count);
    }



    /****  This is the point where i am trying to rollback insert query ,but it's not happening , instead it's inserting the data into the table and just throwing exception , rollback is not happeneing  ****/  
    @Transactional(rollbackFor={DataAccessException.class})
    public void Test(){
        jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into test1 (id, nam) values (4, 'A')");
        throw new DataAccessException("error") {
        };
    }

}
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
package com.cgiri.javabrains.Spring4;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.cgiri.javabrains.Spring4" })
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;


    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource getBasicDataSource()
    {
        BasicDataSource dao = new BasicDataSource();
        dao.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driverClassName"));
        dao.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
        dao.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.userName"));
        dao.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
        dao.setInitialSize(2);
        dao.setMaxActive(5);
        return dao;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager getTransactionManager(BasicDataSource dataSource) {
        DataSourceTransactionManager manager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
        return manager;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }



}
```

And for locking the table during DML query, if 2 or more people are updating simultaneously on table , this locking mechanism is taken care by mysql server or we have to configure separately for that the way we are doing for transactions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `@Transactional` then you could try to use `TransactionTemplate` and something like this:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate;

@Component
public SimpleDao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

    private void executeTransactionWithoutResult(DbTransactionTask dbTask) {
        transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
                dbTask.executeTask();
            }
        });
    }

    public void test() {
        DbTransactionTask dbTask = new DbTransactionTask() {
            @Override
            public void executeTask() {
                try {
                    jdbcTemplate.execute("LOCK TABLES Entry WRITE;");
                    jdbcTemplate.execute("...");
                    jdbcTemplate.execute("...");
                    jdbcTemplate.execute("UNLOCK TABLES;")
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Cause rollback of transaction
                    throw new RuntimeException("Reverting DB operations: " + e.getClass().getSimpleName() + " - " + e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        };

        executeTransactionWithoutResult(dbTask);    
    }

    abstract class DbTransactionTask { public abstract void executeTask(); }
}
```

**EDIT:** With `@Transactional` you could try something like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import dao.EntryDao;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringTransactional {
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

    @Autowired
    private EntryDao dao;

    public void init() {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(SpringTransactional.class);
        springContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringTransactional st = new SpringTransactional();
        try {
            st.init();
            dao.db_transaction_test();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            st.springContext.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Where **EntryDao** is:

```
package dao;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * DB creation and schema:
 * CREATE DATABASE db_name;
 * CREATE USER db_username;
 * <p>
 * USE db_name;
 * GRANT ALL ON db_name.* TO db_username;
 * <p>
 * SET PASSWORD FOR spz = PASSWORD('username123');
 * FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
 * <p>
 * CREATE TABLE Entry (
 * entry_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 * name   TEXT NOT NULL,
 * <p>
 * PRIMARY KEY (entry_ID)
 * );
 */
@Component
public class EntryDao {
    /**
     * application.properties:
     * spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
     * spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
     * spring.datasource.username = db_username
     * spring.datasource.password = username123
     */
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional
    public void db_transaction_test() {
        jdbcTemplate.execute("LOCK TABLES Entry WRITE;");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                int entry_name = getEntryId("entry_" + i);
                System.out.println("Created entry id=" + entry_name);
            } catch (EntryDao.DaoException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (i == 5) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Testing data upload procedure break.");
            }
        }

        jdbcTemplate.execute("UNLOCK TABLES;")
    }

    public int getEntryId(String entryName) throws DaoException {
        List<DbEntry> dbEntries = retrieveEntriesFor(entryName);

        if (dbEntries.size() == 1) {
            return dbEntries.get(0).getEntry_ID();
        } else if (dbEntries.size() == 0) {
            String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO Entry (name) VALUES (?)";
            jdbcTemplate.update(sqlInsert, entryName);
            dbEntries = retrieveEntriesFor(entryName);
            if (dbEntries.size() == 1) {
                return dbEntries.get(0).getEntry_ID();
            } else {
                throw new DaoException("Invalid results amount received after creating new (" + dbEntries.size() + ") when getting entry for name: " + entryName);
            }
        } else {
            throw new DaoException("Invalid results amount received (" + dbEntries.size() + ") when getting entry for name: " + entryName);
        }
    }

    private List<DbEntry> retrieveEntriesFor(String entryName) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM Entry WHERE name=?;", (ResultSet result, int rowNum) -> unMarshal(result), entryName);
    }

    private DbEntry unMarshal(ResultSet result) throws SQLException {
        DbEntry dbEntry = new DbEntry();
        dbEntry.setEntry_ID(result.getInt("entry_ID"));
        dbEntry.setName(result.getString("name"));
        return dbEntry;
    }

    public class DbEntry {
        private int entry_ID;
        private String name;

        int getEntry_ID() { return entry_ID; }
        void setEntry_ID(int entry_ID) { this.entry_ID = entry_ID; }
        public String getName() { return name; }
        public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    }

    public class DaoException extends Throwable { DaoException(String err_msg) { super(err_msg); } }
}
```

Comment: can you please give answer while using @Transactioanl  ? thanks

Comment: Hi @alwi , i added my code where exactly i am getting the problem , i should have done this from  starting.  Sorry for the confusion . Thanks

Comment: Try to put: `@Autowired private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;` and  `@Transactional(rollbackFor={DataAccessException.class}) public void Test() { jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into test1 (id, nam) values (4, 'A')");  throw new DataAccessException("error"); }` in the same Spring `@Component`. Othervise (if you need it in separate classes) I'd suggest to use `TransactionTemplate` - I've added examples for both cases above...

Comment: Hi @alwi , how to put lock while updating/modifying( like insert, delete ) on table ?

Comment: If 2 or more clients are updating simultaneously on same table, then we have to take care of locking. Transactions mostly give us isolation (+integrity) - so the data coming from first client is not used by another until it is complete (whole set of operations is finished/commited). NOTE: it is also depending on isolation level configured in DBMS.
For locking you can use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` (etc. to lock rows) or SQL `LOCK TABLES` (and later `UNLOCK`) statements to lock whole tables within your transactions - depending on what exactly you want to achieve (but beware the deadlocks)...

Comment: in above code that i pasted , 1) where and what exactly i need to mention for locking full table (syntax in terms of java code) ?    2)transaction take care of locking rows while inserting/updating rows or we need to explicitly provide condition , if yes then what will be that condition in term of java code ? Please explain.  Thanks

Comment: You could try to create lock with `jdbcTemplate.execute("LOCK TABLES test1 WRITE;")` at the beginning and `jdbcTemplate.execute("UNLOCK TABLES;")` at the end. Depending on which tables you're going to eventually lock and use in between of these you'd have to consider deadlocks. NOTE: I didn't try it (with jdbcTemplate) and I'm not sure if it doesn't interfere with Spring transaction handling if another process/thread tries the same. So please treat it merely as a suggestion... Typically another thread trying to do `LOCK TABLES test1 WRITE` would have to wait for `UNLOCK` from previous one...

Comment: I just checked it and it works as expected. Other instances of application are waiting on `jdbcTemplate.execute("LOCK TABLES test1 WRITE;")` when one of them already called it but didn't yet invoke `jdbcTemplate.execute("UNLOCK TABLES;")` and so they are actually synchronizing themselves. I've added code for such synchronization to examples above.